# Google/Bing Maps load on dynamically generated div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, bing-maps

How can I load Bing/Google Maps on a dynamically generated div?

Example

```
<div id="cont"></div>

...

$('#cont').append('<div id="mapDiv" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>');//dynamically add div

var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map($("mapDiv"), myOptions);//Bing/Google maps
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in adding Google Maps or Bing Maps on a dynamic node.

But you should change your code a little bit, in order to properly use the HTML node with [0]. And don't forget the #

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map($("#mapDiv")[0], myOptions);//Bing/Google maps
```